# Accounts provided by ganache-cli has no balance at all

Tags: blockchain, ganache

I have initiated a new private test ganache chain by the following commands.

`>ganache-cli --db ./db`

The `db` folder is newly created folder so its content is completely empty.
I can see those results from console.

```
Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)
eth_blockNumber
eth_blockNumber

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0x57d1037Ff1E3649e3d8b39f8d5977cDe7cFFa233 (100 ETH)
(1) 0xeF60A65e944f0De168EC7ae1E9058bBCC6441682 (100 ETH)
(2) 0xd68AA0635a6677ca20C7471cB17BD2CC2F81f2d6 (100 ETH)
(3) 0x2bD8Ab5d71bdbA78D69b4dc9f4d197E0e4C5D80B (100 ETH)
(4) 0x0a464D9a83889321dfEf3BaF4ffC4344832Ea5c9 (100 ETH)
(5) 0xE5909D5E1488BCddaABd56fd982032659F84118C (100 ETH)
(6) 0xc6b5610DF29849315Ab4694b9bFD6a6DBba215B8 (100 ETH)
(7) 0xcD49EdF273a172B1f852B4c95846d0a3e1D36638 (100 ETH)
(8) 0xd9c559d713837717f5d35814a55443902302Ee16 (100 ETH)
(9) 0xbC1e089E03B72c9FA91DeC5fc2d17D8865F6333B (100 ETH)

Private Keys
==================
(0) 0x9f1ec8b7191984ff76d1743ae0d31123c80e8b4068f293240b34f97a73cf531e
(1) 0x05c619bedbf5f5d40fa1b9cf8aadd568c49a1d6f4d3b94d605edc59b84db996d
(2) 0x94dd1c73df460136a90d2d0b0f8bd168aa84c0d0feba55ab5882d1334079841a
(3) 0x63d10010648e70e192949a824dfba0e0dd36d61482e33e101317a1ba6d03171b
(4) 0x2ec411ed4307f200e6e9fbf6bf7ac6bf57ee68cbc48eb4b1f5ee9d8ce4aab9b0
(5) 0xb538d3e3c21692d900a17c2fce637278e50530f0c3553518f0cbe1433a77cdbf
(6) 0xf629936e0434e33634f54e5a1737e4db7fe3084876eea9d2e9e2af4c263ad898
(7) 0x2470acc3e6f443d45a9a61cbcc16790e4ea4d151636fe9ea500880cd458eaabd
(8) 0x42eba3965d6ccfb67b3cd0c233ee393e801e9c9846bc775184b45b5f62c81adf
(9) 0xaf396c13f47205170bab7bb65db5776602d5ee9a8ff2b3a3947ce994c9b45560

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      slow token kind frequent elite poem answer reject okay then cradle motor
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Gas Price
==================
20000000000

Gas Limit
==================
6721975

Call Gas Limit
==================
9007199254740991

Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545
```

But I found that the above accounts' balances are all `0 ETH` from metamask.
Metamask's target chain was set to `localhost:8545` which is ganache's RPC url.

It works well with ganache UI but not work properly with ganach-cli.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I do have the same issue even connecting from Metamask, or Truffle, or Remix to my local ganache, they all show all accounts with 0ETH

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it.

1. Remove the localhost:8545 network in MetaMask. The "localhost" requires a network connection. It's better to specify 127.0.0.1
2. Add a new network with the values:

   - New RPC URL: HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545
   - Chain ID: 1337
   - Currency: eth

Note the above is for ganache CLI;
Ganache runs on HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

SWITCH ACCOUNT -> CREATE NEW WORKSPACE. You will get new accounts with 100 ETH.

[image: screenshot for SWITCH option]

Comment: OP specifically said "It works well with ganache UI but not work properly with ganach-cli."

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder `./db` and restart ganache

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

The first time when you run `ganache-cli --db ./db`, ganache will generate 10 accounts with 100 Eth using randon seed. But the next time when you run `ganache-cli --db ./db`, 10 random account will regenerate without 100 Eth.
So to solve this, you can make these 10 accounts no longer randomly generated. The additional parameters: `--wallet.deterministic=true`.